# Best way to add items to a list in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

Essentially, I want to get the names of all .zip files in a given directory and unzip them.  Right now, I'm working on just getting the names of the files into some sort of array or list.  It's grabbing the files correctly, but I don't know a whole lot about VBScript, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
Dim fileList

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objStartFolder = "C:\Test"

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
    Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path

    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "ZIP" Then
            Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
            'Add file names to fileList variable
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

There is...

```
' using vbArray
ReDim fileArray(-1)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Test"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "ZIP" Then
        ReDim Preserve fileArray(UBound(fileArray) + 1)
        fileArray(UBound(fileArray)) = objFile.Name
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo Join(fileArray, vbNewLine)

' using .NET ArrayList (as no biult-in Lists in VBScript)
Dim fileList
Set fileList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "ZIP" Then
        fileList.Add objFile.Name
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo Join(fileList.ToArray, vbNewLine)
```

**P.P.S:**

Is Files collection dynamic:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(curDir)
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

WScript.Echo "Files count: " & oFiles.Count

Set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(oFSO.GetTempName)
oFile.Close

WScript.Echo "Files count: " & oFiles.Count
```

[EDIT] But looks like then iterate VBS use snapshot of `Files` collection, so we can presume that unzip may go safety without need of file list.

Comment: Consider using plain Dim fileArray and/or pre-declaring the size of the array (the .Capacity of the ArrayList), because when working with a .Files Collection you know the number elements before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you have the files in a collection already (colFiles), the first reason to have a collection of items - process them in turn - does not make you put them in a second list. Why not just unzip each file instead of putting it in a list? To unzip a file A you don't need info about/access to the other files X in the folder. So the second reason for a collection - needing all elements at the same time/when processing one item - doesn't apply either.

If you insist on a second list, all depends on what you want to do with it/the items. If you just want a list of names, the easiest way would be to put the names/pathes as keys in a **Dictionary**. If you want the names sorted, a **System.Collections.ArrayList/SortedList** will be more convenient. If you want to work with more properties/attributes of the files - size, dates, access rights, ... - a **Disconnected ADODB Recordset** will allow you to store all those properties in a (SQL) Table.

Last, but not least, a simple native VBScript **Array** (dimensioned for the attributes for each file) could be used: As you know the possible number of elements (colFiles.Count), you can define the size of the array before the loop, assign the items in the loop, and ReDim Preserve it after looping.

Take your pick, and I'll add sample code to this posting.

P.S.:

As @Panayot gave you sample code for Arrays and ArrayLists, it would make sense to ask for an ADO Recordset.

**P.P.S:**

For worriers:

```
  Dim oFS : Set oFS  = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
  Dim sDir : sDir      = "..\testdata\testFilesCollection"

  Dim nFile, sFile, oFile, i

  If oFS.FolderExists( sDir ) Then oFS.DeleteFolder sDir
  oFS.CreateFolder sDir

  WScript.Echo "----- Creating", cnMax, "files"
  For nFile = 1 To cnMax
      sFile = nFile & ".txt"
      oFS.CreateTextFile oFS.BuildPath( sDir, sFile )
      WScript.Echo sFile, "created"
  Next
  WScript.Echo "----- Looping over", cnMax, "files and creating", cnMax, "more"
  i = 0
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder( sDir ).Files
      If i <= cnMax Then
         sFile = Chr(65 + i) & ".txt"
         oFS.CreateTextFile oFS.BuildPath( sDir, sFile )
      End If
      i = i + 1
      WScript.Echo oFile.Name, "seen", sFile, "created"
  Next
  WScript.Echo "----- Looping over", 2 * cnMax, "files"
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder( sDir ).Files
      WScript.Echo oFile.Name, "seen"
  Next
```

output:

```
----- Creating 3 files
1.txt created
2.txt created
3.txt created
----- Looping over 3 files and creating 3 more
2.txt seen A.txt created
3.txt seen B.txt created
1.txt seen C.txt created
----- Looping over 6 files
B.txt seen
2.txt seen
C.txt seen
A.txt seen
3.txt seen
1.txt seen
```

[The files collection is a snapshot] == @Panayot's argument/evidence ==> The `For Each` loops over a snapshot of the Files collection - at least wrt additions. Testing for deletions is left as an exercise.

Comment: It's maybe a very concrete case though to bother me, but if we unpack archives to the same folder without storing them in array or list, are we not risk to unpack and their sub archives too? Files is not a "snapshot" but dynamic collection.

Comment: @PanayotKarabakalov - please see P.P.S.

Comment: I may test your code later on, but I see you get fresh instance of Files collection, and end with conclusion that it's not dynamic. Now I'll edit my answer above and will append a very sample code.

Comment: I test your code, very interesting! If I go with `Set oFile` for creating and use `oFile.Close` inside For-loop, then I have error on the `oFile.Name`, but if I go like you, it works. Strange... Most interesting is that if you keep an instance of Files collection, it's seen that it's dynamic, but looks like VBS use a snapshot copy of Files then iterate with For-loop. That was very helpful to me (+1).

Comment: Obviously I'm pretty absent today :) I overwrite the variable with file stream and it's normal to get error on `.Name` property.